# Django, detect if model field is inherited

Tags: django, database, inheritance, django-mptt

I'd like to check if a model field is inherited, similar to `Field.is_relation`. Is there a way to tell?

I have a model that inherits from `MPTTModel` and I want a list of the attributes defined directly in the model but not in `MPTTModel`.

E.g.:

```
# models.py
class ACoolModel(MPTTModel):
    name = CharField(max_length=128)
```

Then, something like:

```
[f.attname for f in ACoolModel._meta.get_fields(False)]
```

Gives back the fields from `MPTTModel` as well:

```
['id', 'name', 'lft', 'rght', 'tree_id', 'level']
```

But I want it to return:

```
['id', 'name']
```

Comment: As an option, you can get a list of attributes for `ACoolModel` and then for  `MPTTModel`. And subtract the first list from the second. You will have the difference of the attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using solution suggested in comments:

```
all_fields = [f.attname for f in ACoolModel._meta.get_fields(False)]
inherited_fields = [f.attname for f in MPTTModel._meta.get_fields(False)]
non_inherited_fields = [field for field in all_fields if field not in inherited_fields]
```